# Sorting alghorytm crashes when trying to print information of list

Tags: c++, list, sorting

In my app, I'd like to sort object ascending and descending. To do this I've written 3 functions. It probably sorts but when I want to print all list I've got error like: Access violation reading location 0x00000000. I think that list is empty but I'm not sure. What's the problem? To sum up: List seems to be empty after sorting. The alghorytm works but the function which prints the list crashes.

JednostkaMaszyny is a basic abstract class.

// This function is responsible for finding the biggest and the lowest ID in list and return it value.

```
int static findID(JednostkaMaszyny*& headOfList, short numberOfObjects,bool ascending)
{
    short i = 0;
    int IDtoFind = 0;

    JednostkaMaszyny* iterator;
    iterator = headOfList;


    /*if(rosnaco)
    {
        IDtoFind = 999999999;
    }
    else
    {
        IDtoFind = 0;
    }*/


    while(i < numberOfObjects)
    {
        if(!ascending){
            if(iterator->getID() > IDtoFind)
            {
                IDtoFind = iterator->getID();
            }

            //i++;
            //iterator = iterator->nextObject;
        }
        else
        {
            if(iterator->getID() < IDtoFind)
            {
                IDtoFind = iterator->getID();
            }


        }
        i++;
            iterator = iterator->nextObject;
    }

    return IDtoFind;
};
```

This function accepts pointer to main list, number of current objects in list and ID.

```
static JednostkaMaszyny*& getObjectAtIDAndAssignItToSortedList(JednostkaMaszyny*& headOfList, short numberOfObjects, int ID)
{
    short i = 0;
    JednostkaMaszyny* iterator;
    JednostkaMaszyny* returnedObject = NULL;
    int tmpBoolNumber;
    bool tmpBool = false;

    iterator = headOfList;

    while(i < iloscObiektow)
    {
        tmpBoolNumber = iterator->getBoolSorted();

        if((iterator->getID() == ID) && tmpBoolNumber)
        {
            cout<<iterator->getID();

            if(typeid(*iterator) == typeid(Desktop))
            {
                 returnedObject = new Desktop(((Desktop*)iterator)->getwysokosc(),((Desktop*)iterator)->getDlugosc(),((Desktop*)iterator)->getSzerokosc(),((Desktop*)iterator)->getClockProcessor()
                     ,((Desktop*)iterator)->getIdNumber(),((Desktop*)iterator)->getprocessorType(),((Desktop*)iterator)->getnameInNetwork(),((Desktop*)iterator)->getID());

                //((Desktop*)iterator) -> setBoolSorted(1);

                break;
            }
            else
            {
                returnedObject = new Laptop(((Laptop*)iterator)->getWagaLaptopa(),((Laptop*)iterator)->getClockProcessor(),((Laptop*)iterator)->getIdNumber(),((Laptop*)iterator)->getprocessorType(),
                    ((Laptop*)iterator)->getnameInNetwork(),((Laptop*)iterator)->getID());

                //((Laptop*)iterator) -> setBoolSorted(1);
                break;
            }
            iterator->setBoolSorted(1);
        }

        i++;
        iterator = iterator->nextObject;
    }

    //iterator->setID(1); I've tried to set attribute of object that it is already sorted but it fails here saying: Access fail to object.......

    return returnedObject;
};
```

And the last one function. It is the main "engine". It accepts pointer to main list, number of objects and helpfull pointer to the last object in list.

```
void static sortListByUser(JednostkaMaszyny*& headOfList, short numberObjects, JednostkaMaszyny*& helpFullPointer)
{
    JednostkaMaszyny* tmpSortedList = NULL;
    JednostkaMaszyny* iterator;
    short choice;
    short numberOfObjects;
    int tmpId;

    numberOfObjects = numberObjects;

    cout<<"1 - Ascending"<<endl;
    cout<<"2 - Descending"<<endl;

    cout<<"Your choice: "; cin>>choice;

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        if(numberOfObjects > 0)
        {
            while(numberOfObjects > 0)
            {
                if(tmpSortedList == NULL)
                {

                    tmpId = findID(headOfList,numberOfObjects,false);
                    tmpSortedList = getObjectAtIDAndAssignItToSortedList(headOfList,numberOfObjects,tmpId);
                    iterator = tmpSortedList;
                    //tmpSortedList->previousObject = NULL;
                    numberOfObjects--;

                }
                else
                {
                    tmpId = findID(headOfList,numberOfObjects,false);
                    iterator->nextObject = getObjectAtIDAndAssignItToSortedList(headOfList,numberOfObjects,tmpId);
                    iterator->nextObject->previousObject = iterator;
                    iterator = iterator->nextObject;

                    numberOfObjects--;
                }

                //iterator->nextObject = NULL;
            }
            //iterator->
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"LISTA JEST PUSTA"<<endl<<endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: In short, simple example code that's only meant to demonstrate a general principle, prefer short identifiers like `Foo` over long, domain-specific identifiers like `JednostkaMaszyny`.

Comment: should get ride of unnecessary code before posting, for example, `short choice` and etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I looked over your functions and tried running it, but I'm missing the rest of your program. However, I think I know what's going wrong in your code by the error you gave me in your original post.

> **ERROR: Access violation reading location 0x00000000**

This kind of error usually means your trying to access a memory address which was never reserved(allocated) in it's respective scope. Since you're trying to read the memory location with the hexadecimal value 0x00000000 which is a 32-bit binary value of all zeros, it's most likely that you're trying to deference a NULL pointer which is undefined behavior. And that this pointer is pointing to a 32-bit data-type which my guess is an integer.

One way to prevent this is to create a conditional statement to test if the pointer is NULL.

```
if (pointer)
    cout << "pointer is pointing to an integer.";
else
    cout << "pointer is a null pointer.";
```

This would explain why your algorithm works but fails when you try to read out the values.

For future questions, try to narrow out the problem and recreate it in a smaller program so myself and others on this site can more easily assist you. In this case, it might be difficult to do so if you don't understand where the problem is in the first place.

---

***DEBUGING TIPS:*** Using breakpoints and the call stack window can help you find where your program is assigning NULL pointers where you don't want them.